# Xslt : From XML to CSV where we have multiple root items that are reoccuring

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, transformation

**I have this data in xml format where there are two root tags occurring many times. These two roots are connected by the key element. Meaning the half of the root1 data is in root2.**

```
<sample_static>

    <root1>
        <elemnent1_key>1112</element1_key>
        <elemnent2>boss</elemnent2>
        <elemnent3>movie</elemnent3>
        <elemnent4>entertainment</elemnent4>
    </root1>
    <root1>
        <elemnent1_key>1113</element1_key>
        <elemnent2>king</elemnent2>
        <elemnent3>position</elemnent3>
        <elemnent4>entertainer</elemnent4>
    </root1>
    <root1>
        <elemnent1_key>1114</element1_key>
        <elemnent2>employee</elemnent2>
        <elemnent3>human</elemnent3>
        <elemnent4>puppet</elemnent4>
    </root1>
    .
    .
    .
    .

    <root2>
        <elemnent5_key>1112</element5_key>
        <elemnent6>good</elemnent6>
        <elemnent7>hit</elemnent7>
        <elemnent8>earning</elemnent8>
    </root2>
    <root2>
        <elemnent5_key>1113</element5_key>
        <elemnent6>loser</elemnent6>
        <elemnent7>duffer</elemnent7>
        <elemnent8>history</elemnent8>
    </root2>
    <root2>
        <elemnent5_key>1114</element5_key>
        <elemnent6>onsite</elemnent6>
        <elemnent7>rejected</elemnent7>
        <elemnent8>switch</elemnent8>
    </root2>
    .
    .
    .
    .

</sample_static>
```

**Desired OUTPUT**:

SO I want to make a csv file in the below format using XSLT mapping.

```
element1_key|elemnent2|elemnent3|elemnent4|elemnent6|elemnent7|elemnent8

1112|boss|movie|entertainment|good|hit|earning

1113|king|position|entertainer|loser|duffer|history

1114|employee|human|puppet|onsite|rejected|switch
```

**I want to connect the root 1 element and root2 element and form a single row using the XSLT only.**

**NOTE: There are many ROOT1 one tags and ROOT2 tags .. for sample i have give 3 root1 and 3 root2 tags to demonstrate the connection.**

Root1's first data can be connected using element1_key 1112 with element5_key 1112

How do we do that? any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather simple to accomplish by using a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="root2" match="root2" use="element5_key" />

<xsl:template match="/sample_static">
    <xsl:for-each select="root1">
        <xsl:for-each select="*|key('root2', element1_key)/*[not(self::element5_key)] ">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

> if there is no root2 for any root 1 the field should be blank.. for
>   example if one root data is like 1113|a|b|c|d|e|f the other can be
>   like 1114|x|y|||||

If you know in advance how many elements there are in `root2`, you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="root2" match="root2" use="element5_key" />

<xsl:template match="/sample_static">
    <xsl:for-each select="root1">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:variable name="root2" select="key('root2', element1_key)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$root2">
                <xsl:for-each select="$root2/*[not(self::element5_key)]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>|||</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Output recieved for this was something like this in a single line


1112bossmovieentertainment1113kingpositionentertainer1114employeehumanpuppet1112goodhitearning1113loserdufferhistory1114onsiterejectedswitch

Comment: @shamsul http://xsltransform.net/bdxtr9 (note that I have corrected your input `elemnent --> element`).

Comment: yes i corrected that in my xml still getting the same. Also for information .. there are more than hundreds of root1 & root2 and for each root1 there is root2. and if there is no root2 for any root 1 the field should be blank.. for example if one root data is like 
1113|a|b|c|d|e|f 
the other can be like 
1114|x|y|||||


what i mean to say is it should also handle if the IF condition does not find any root2 for some root1 ...

Comment: "*in my xml still getting the same*" Then your XML is different. Or your processor is non-conforming. I cannot tell from here. -- Re the other thing: is the structure of `root2` (i.e. the names of the elements) known in advance?

Comment: I have updated the question please tell me for the original XML now. This count of the tags may vary. so our dependancy should not be on the count of the tags. i am just asking to consider the situation if in case the root2 is missing for any root1.

Comment: Bang on ..You have hit the bulls eye. output for you previous xslt is 
**1112|boss|movie|entertainment|good|hit|earning**

**1113|king|position|entertainer|loser|duffer|history**

**1114|employee|human|puppet|onsite|rejected|switch**




\n
But can you also give me the xslt for the original XML updated in the Question


Also suppose a manin tag static which contains book_static tag.. i tried putting that in question but it  was not accepting so mentioning it here explicitly

Comment: @shamsul I've shown how you how; the implementation is up to you.

Comment: Still i am new to xslt ... if you can explain the code i can implement it accordingly ...

Comment: If you have a *specific* question, I can try and answer it.

Comment: I am raising a new question with some specific details.